# Create temporary table with gorm

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am trying to create a temporary table with gorm (SQLite3) and was not successful.

I could put it in the `temp` schema like this ...

```
func (MyType) TableName() string {
    return "temp.my_type"
}
```

... but then I guess I need two connections access two schemas, which I want to avoid.

Is there some way to communicate to gorm that a table should be temporary?